# Amazon SNS android device tokens limit for push notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

There is possibility to send same message to multiple devices of Android platform. we have a requirement to add multiple device tokens to same payload.. but I am not sure on device tokens limit to add for payload.

any idea on limit of device tokens?

Note: Here we are not depended on topic to send push notification

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FCM/GCM to send the notification, there is a limit of 1000 devices. In case you want to add more number of devices just split the firebase id's in set of 1000.

Comment: Thanks for reply... I am using FCM with limit of 1000 devices..wanted to know more about Amazon SNS.

Answer (score 0):

I think your direct question is “can we send the push notification on multiple devices in one go by using AWS SNS (Without Topic)”.

In this case there is no readymade option available from AWS SNS to send the push notification on multiple devices Without Topic.

However using AWSSNS Client you can write your own logic (Iterating over device-Token) to achieve this.